# Write and read data to the MemoryStream

Tags: c#

I am try to write some data to the `MemoryStream`, and then correctly read it. For example :

```
int someValue = 10;
Console.WriteLine(someValue);
Console.ReadKey();
MemoryStream lMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();

StreamWriter lStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(lMemoryStream);
lStreamWriter.Write(someValue);

StreamReader lStreamReader = new StreamReader(lMemoryStream);
int someValue2 = lStreamReader.Read();
Console.WriteLine(someValue2);
Console.ReadKey();
```

But in response I get empty memoryStream, and get value -1. What's wrong?

Comment: see about [MemoryStream.Seek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.memorystream.seek(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to flush your data into the stream. You also have to set the position to 0 if you want to read data from the beginning.

```
lStreamWriter.Flush(); // after .Write!
lMemoryStream.Position = 0; // before read!
```

Tip: Don't close the writer, it will also close the MemoryStream. Close it after you're done with the data.

Comment: Or do the reading with:
Encoding.SOMETHING.GetString(yourstream.GetBuffer(), 0, yourstream.Length); // reading the whole buffer and returning it as a string with the specified encoding

Comment: i take wrong data...`int someValue = 10;
            
            MemoryStream lMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            StreamWriter lStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(lMemoryStream);

            lStreamWriter.Write(someValue);
            lStreamWriter.Flush();
            lMemoryStream.Position = 0;
            StreamReader lStreamReader = new StreamReader(lMemoryStream);
            int someValue2 = lStreamReader.Read();
            `  i get wrong value 49

Comment: @Imorian Nope, that's the right value. You're writing the value as string `"10"`, and the first byte of that string is `(byte)'1' == 49`. If you want to get `"10"` back, you can do eg. `lStreamReader.ReadToEnd();`

Comment: Exactly. The best way of getting the whole data (like I said in my first comment):
byte[] buffer = lMemoryStream.ToArray();
string Data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

Comment: but if a have a few filds to write?

Comment: If you have few fields to write, work with offsets to read specific data.

Answer (score 2):

When you write to stream, you advance your position (in said stream). To read the value you've just written you have to "rewind" your position (by setting it).

Comment: Via the Position property, or a call to Seek().

Comment: @Imorian You write to the MemoryStream with `lStreamWriter.Write(someValue)`